# Efficient way to load large json object with ftp:///

Tags: javascript, html, json, ftp-client

I have a large json object (up to 200 MB or more). It stores the values required to render graph by plotly.js.

I have tried to incorporate the json object into html by using `text/javascript` and `application/json` or stored the json in external javascript code and load it with the script tag. Both approach cost lots of time to load the HTML page (about 20-30 sec).

Since I cannot read the local files with `ftp:///` protocol, which is blocked by the chrome due to **CORS policy** for security reason, I cannot store the data in local file, and read it later.

Is there a more efficient way to embed the large json files in the html files? Maybe we could evaluate the codes with json object later?

Comment: Why not split up the file?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because all the data are needed. There are about 30,000s features and 10,000 samples. I want to let user to choose what feature they want to display.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.
First, define the data in the `global variable` with a js file.
Second, load the js file later with a click on the button or other events.

```
// data.js
window.data = [1, 2, 3]

// load the data with the script tag.
const scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "./data.js";
scriptTag.onload = () => console.log("loaded")
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

So now, I can split large data into separate variables and load later.

Answer (score -1):

When using the `<script>` tag, use the `async` and `defer` attributes as well as `onload` to start the drawing when the file is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion. I tried it and don't really help the loading speed. I think the `async` and `defer` are for downloading the js files at the same time when DOM was parsing. My js file is in the local, I guess there's no need to download. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that the delay of page loading (or page freezing even if all html elements have shown) is because of the reading of large js file into memory.